# Web Development IDE with that indents HTML correctly

Tags: html, ide

I am currently looking for a web development IDE that highlights the syntax of html and more important, indents the html-code correctly. I have tried Dreamweaver but it doesn't seem to have a feature for auto-indenting html-code while you're typing. I also have tried NotePad++ and Aptana 3.0 but no luck with both.

So I was wondering if anyone knows a web development IDE that meets my needs.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (I'm java web developer). IDEA makes high-quality formatting code in any language, including in an HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a very very good editor. For indenting u can try ctrl+shift+f key combinations.

Also you can use Aptana Studio. It is free as well as a very good editor.

Answer (score 0):

[Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) is a browser-based IDE, and the editor text editor (Ace) was originally developed for Web Languages (HTML/JS/CSS) so it supports them quite well.

Again though, this is *browser based*, so if you're looking for a local-only tool this may not be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest VS Code. Because...

1. It's dev by Microsoft
2. Very good suggestions and autocomplete feature
3. Code folding feature. It will be extremely useful when coding for big websites
4. Interactive layout and amazing color themes
5. Live server plug in support which us good for checking the output live .

However, At the end any IDE you'd b using it will help very much so go with something suggested by the instructor during the course. It will be lot ore easy to use!!